Have a python puzzle with recursion specifically factorial()
Am puzzled by factorial response
def factorial(i):
  if(i)
    j = i * factorial(i-1)
  else:
    j = 1
  return j

factorial(0) produces 1.
factorial(3) produces 6.
But if I change j to j = 2, the result is 12:
def factorial(i):
  if(i)
    j = i * factorial(i-1)
  else:
    j = 2
  return j

factorial(0) produces 2.
factorial(3) produces 12.
factorial(4) produces 48
How did the value of j come into play? How did it become a multiplier?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Set J to 1 --> (0! = J = 1), (1! = 1 * 0! = 1 * J = 1 * 1 = 1), (2! = 2 * 1! = 2 * (1 * 0!) = 2 * (1 * J) = 2 * (1 * 1) = 2 * 1 = 2), (3! = … = 3 * (2 * (1 * J)) = … = 6). Now try with J = 2, and remember, if in doubt then use a breakpoint.

It becomes a multiplier here i * factorial(i-1)

Why has the question been wrongfully closed with an incorrect reason stated? This post asks for the purpose of a specific variable and how it mutates the chain of recursive calls while the implied "already answered question" asks for something more broad and general (verbatim: "how recursion works").

@M.A. If you understand this answer, I feel fairly confident that this question answers itself. If not, and OP really needs more clarification, they'll need to specify more clearly what information they're missing.

Note that if (i) in this context means, if i > 0, that's how j comes to play.
This is what you probably want to do:
def factorial(i):
    if i == 0:
        return 1
    return i * factorial(i - 1)


print(factorial(0))
print(factorial(3))
print(factorial(4))


Prints
1
6
24

Comment
@alan2here: When a "return" occurs then the rest of the function does not, it doesn't get that far, so it's like having a built if "else" clause, either the "if" happens or it does not and therefore the rest of the function happens instead.

Note to OP that when a "return" occurs then the rest of the function does not, it doesn't get that far, so it's like having a built if "else" clause, either the "if" happens or it does not and therefore the rest of the function happens instead.


How did the value of j come into play? How did it become a multiplier?

When your recursion unwinds upon reaching the base case, it assigns 2 to j (which is wrong as per the calculation of the factorial function), which then subsequently multiplies the whole chain of multiplication by 2 instead of by 1.
If you don't want to use user24714692's answer, then update your recursive call by correctly setting j to 1 in your base case:
def factorial(i):
  if(i):
    j = i * factorial(i-1)
  else:
    j = 1  # Not 2
  return j


Further Reading
Please, go through Chapter 4 of Goodrich, Tamassia & Goldwasser (2013) for stronger grasp on the theory of recursion and recursive base cases.
